# Field with Count of Records in Related List

Tags: trigger, related-list, roll-up-summary

My Opportunities have a lookup field (Lookup__c) to specific Accounts. I have a related list of these Opportunities on these Accounts. Now, I need a custom field (Qty_of_Opportunities__c) on my Account that has the count of Opportunities in that related list. Rollup Summaries won't work as this isn't a master-detail relationship, it's a lookup. This custom field will be used in reports.

From my googling, looks like I'm going to need a trigger but I've never written or implemented one. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some resources that will help you:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cO3O4yMv7w
- http://www.salesforcetutorial.com/apex-trigger-create-simple-trigger/
- http://www.sfdc99.com/2013/05/12/example-how-to-write-a-simple-apex-trigger-2
- [How to write simple after update trigger on Account Object?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25463/how-to-write-simple-after-update-trigger-on-account-object)